# Bind and refresh scope variable with a select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm doing some work with my api and found that my scope variable used in the same script doesn't update:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<select name="equipo" ng-model="selector">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
selector: {{selector}}
    url: {{url}}
<div>
  <p ng-repeat="j in myData">
    {{ j.nombre }}
  </p>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.selector = "1";
    $scope.url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/equipos/"+$scope.selector+"/jugadores";

  $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/equipos/"+$scope.selector+"/jugadores").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      console.log($scope.myData);});
});
</script>
```

when a change the option in my input the url ($scope.url) doesn't change. Any tips or things that i am missing?

Comment: You have to make the request each time the option is changed - it wont do it automatically. Checkout `ngChange`

Comment: worked fine! i called a function change, and did there the changes. Thanks u!